# De donde proviene la frase "cuide sus efectos personales"

Tags: expresiones

En más de una ocasión he leído carteles que dicen algo como:

[Por favor,] **cuide sus efectos personales** [, no nos responsabilizamos por pérdidas]

O algunas variaciones siempre usando la palabra **efecto**

[image: Imagen de ejemplo]

Siempre he entendido tal afirmación como sinónimo de

[blah, bla] *cuide sus pertenencias* [bla, bla].

Al consultar la palabra [efecto](http://dle.rae.es/efecto) en el diccionario de la RAE, no encuentro un significado de *pertenencia* para dicha palabra, lo más cercano es:

> *4.* m. Artículo de comercio.

Sin embargo, a mi manera de ver las cosas, no es suficiente. Por ejemplo, puedo llevar dentro de mis pertenencias una cartera hecha por mi mismo, o el suéter que me hizo mi tía.

Por otro lado, buscándo [sinónimos de efecto](http://www.wordreference.com/sinonimos/efecto) en WordReference, encuentro esto:

> - enseres, mercadería, mercancía, muestras, productos, útiles, artículos, **pertenencias**

Mis dudas concretas son:

- ¿es correcto el uso de la palabra *efecto* como sinónimo de *pertenencia* en este caso?
- Si no lo es, ¿qué significa realmente la frase?
- ¿de donde proviene su uso?
- ¿Sería correcto usar la palabra *efecto* como sinónimo de *pertenencia* en otros casos, por ejemplo: estoy vendiendo mis efectos? (la cual no suena natural para mi).

Comment: Si haces busqueda en paginas Españolas, unico uso de "efectos personales" que se encuentra es en la frase "efectos personales y partimioniales".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según lo indicado en el siguiente punto de la RAE sí es correcto.

> [efecto](http://dle.rae.es/efecto).
>
> 9 . m. pl. Bienes, muebles, enseres.

La "pl" de plural es decir como en el caso de "efectos personales". Sin embargo, como nativo nunca he oido que se emplee en otro caso con la misma definición.

Comment: http://www.linguee.es/espanol-ingles/traduccion/efectos+personales.html cierto que parece ser su correcto su uso, el origen parece ser de una cutre traducción del inglés. Casi siempre que lo veo escrito me parece más apropiado equipaje, o pertenencias. Quizás haya otras diez maneras mejores de escribir "efectos personales"

Comment: @Ernesto yo también creo que hay mejores maneras para decir lo mismo, de allí la curiosidad sobre su origen, pues no suena muy natural para mi, y realmente no se usa en el lenguaje del día a día.